# Layering background images from separate styles using css/html

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to be able to layer two (or more) **.png** images on top of one another while calling each image from its own **separate/distinct** style.

Using multiple backgrounds in one style does not help me in this case, as I'd like to have the image of a **"door"** with a transparent background show on top of a variety of **"floor tiles"** at will. The door is a separate style, each floor tile is a separate style. I wouldn't want to create an additional combo style for every possible combination of door and floor, which is what the multiple background function within one style would force me to do.

I also would like to not employ an img if possible as I will later have additional graphics (characters and monsters) be appearing on top of the floor and door tiles which I will introduce as img.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use oocss is object oriented css http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/

Answer (score 0):

When applying multiple background images (about 20% of the way down https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-image/), you need to comma-separate images, meaning packing them into the same style. CSS3 doesn't allow you to alter a single image in the stack.

So, there are a couple options open to you:

- Use multiple elements that overlay each other. Using absolute positioning allows for overlaying items.
- Use pseudo elements (::before, ::after) in order to apply images over the parent image.

Both are essentially the same. Here's some boilerplate code:

```
<div class="game-window">
  <div class="game-background walls"></div>
  <div class="game-backgroud tiles"></div>
</div>
```

Then, you can style the backgrounds accordingly to stretch the window:

```
.game-window {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px; /* Old school */
}

.game-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.walls {
  background: url(/images/walls.png);
}

...
```

Without z-indexing, the last HTML element will render on the top of your image stack.